# C# group database query result into nested generics list

Tags: c#, generics

I am getting query data back from a stored procedure, and I need to group this into 3 generic lists. I'm not sure how to get this right.

Here is what the query result from the data looks like in summary:

```
Child   |   Parent  |   GrandChildren
a2      |   a1      |   a30
a2      |   a1      |   a31
a2      |   a1      |   a32

b2      |   b1      |   b30
b2      |   b1      |   b31

c2      |   c1      |   c30

d2      |   d1      |   d30
d2      |   d1      |   d31
d3      |   d1      |   d32
d3      |   d1      |   d33
```

Here is how I want to group the data.

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name  { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<GrandChild> GrandChildren { get; set; }
}

public class GrandChild
{
    // numerous properties.
}
```

Here is what I've tried, but with no luck.

```
var data = Repository.GetData();
var groupedData = from d in data
                    where d.Parent > 0
                    group d by d.Parent into ParentGroup
                    select parentGroup.ToList();

// Result: Grouped list of "Parent", not with grouped "Child" and grouped "GrandChildren" as per desired structure above.
```

Comment: You're going to have to group the grandchildren, too.  It's not going to happen automatically.  I would try creating the grandchild grouping first, then group the children together, then read each parent.  This is going to be a fairly hairy expression when you're done. I'd be worried about query run times.

Comment: @Tony thanks for the quick response. Please could you give me a start in how to group the grandchildren as I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to group the grandchildren, too. Something like this:

```
var data = Repository.GetData();

// Group the Grandchildren first
var grandkids = from d in data
                where d.Child > 0
                group d by d.Child into GrandChildGroup
                select new Grandchild {
                    // Assign grand child properties here
                };

// Group the Children
var children = from d in data
               where d.Parent > 0
               group d by d.Parent into ChildGroup
               select new Child {
                   // Assign child properties here
                   Grandchildren = ( from gc in grandkids
                                     where gc.Parent = d.Child
                                     select gc ).ToList()
               };

// Now group the parents
var groupedData = from p in data
                  select new Parent {
                      // Assign parent properties here
                      Children = ( from kid in children
                                   where kid.Parent = p.Parent
                                   select kid ).ToList()
                  }.ToList();
```